# Как вести два почти идентичных проекта backend

Tags: postgresql, api, backend, микросервисы, project-management

хотелось бы получить совета
Есть проект созданный для нашего рынка, с ним планируется выходить на иностранный рынок
функционал на другом рынке будет немного отличаться(немного другая регистрация, другие данных из таблиц(списки городов например))

Как лучше вести подобные проекты?

- Разделить отличающийся модули на микросервисы?
- Сделать отдельный репозиторий и вести проект сразу в двух?

Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, был бы рад услышать советы

Comment: Просто реализовать оба варианта в одном проекте и включать нужный вариант через настройки проекта?

Comment: оба варианта должны работать параллельно

Comment: Вам что-то мешает запустить их параллельно с двумя разными настройками?

Comment: Поддержу вопрос автора. Сам сталкивался с тем, что 2 сервиса имели больше 70 процетов одинакового функционала, и как следствие, одинакового кода. Данное решение, понятное дело, не являлось хорошим решением, но разделить их было принято в связи с тем, что один сервис работает с данными из разных внешний очередей, а один берет данные из других наших сервисов. То есть принципиально запихнуть 2 логики в 1 проект не получалось. Но вот комментарий про "запустить с настройками натолкнул меня на вопрос, а как можно это сделать в рамках деплоя через k8s"?

Comment: Продолжая комментарий выше: Думаю, наверное самым лучшим и простым решением будет передавать в env значение, которое будет регулировать режим работы, например? И тогда вся логика необходимая будет содержаться в одном проекте

Comment: @Ivan *"один сервис работает с данными из внешний очередей, а один берет данные из других наших сервисов"*  --- для этого обычно используют какой-нибудь SOLID и щепотку паттернов)) и потом через настройки впихивается нужный класс для работы)

Comment: Ну и фраза "другие данных из таблиц" это прям вот сходу нарушение принципа `D`. Получается что весь проект зависит от каких-то данных в БД. А так не должно быть. Должна быть бизнес-логика и какие-то данные, неважно откуда, хоть от голубя принесенные.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, проблема была в том, как это скейлить. У нас есть сервис А, который работает на 100 инстансов и сервис Б, который скейлится по факту нарастания нагрузки из наших сервисов. Как на уровне k8s все это можно разрулить?

Comment: Все регистрация/авторизация должна быть модульной. что бы любые способы работали по одному и тому же api, различались только параметрами говорящими какой модуль использовать. Все модули в одном репозитории. Одно API может вполне обслуживать запросы для любых рынков. Там где данные бека отличаются вероятно нужен только параметр указывающий на страну например